# Left constraints in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

So I'm doing a tut on iOS 9 development with Xcode 7, and in the example I'm currently doing the instruction is adding constraints using ctrl+drag and clicking on a second image. Now my issues isn't with that process, my issue is when the video asks me to set left constraints (the right image attached) I don't have that option (the left side of the image attached). I tried "leading" just to see what it would do and it did not achieve desired results. I'm guessing that this is changed in Xcode 7 and there is a new method of achieving this result?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: To update my question as per a suggestion below, here's what's happening. I have a background image view. When I am lining up image buttons along the background image, the first one is just fine, once I select the second one, and add the leading constraint, then lock in the width and height in the main constraints - it flies off the page somewhere. The background image is horizontally and vertically aligned to the container, and the main reason I'm doing this is I have "landscape mode" pulled up in a main preview window and I want to make sure that everything is looking good in that mode.

I have tried starting a new project all together and I get the same result. Again the tutorial I'm following was using Xcode 7 beta, so not sure if that has something to do with it. I'd like to lock in on the problem instead of skipping over it in case I run into this in the future.

Thanks!

[image: Xcode 7 question]

Comment: There are other ways to set constraints in storyboard. Use the buttons in the bottom right corner of the window. If you add the left constraint there, it should automatically constrain it to the nearest neighbor view.

Comment: After you have added the constraint you can edit and select `left` rather than `leading` but generally left and leading are interchangeable and `leading` is preferred; Leading/trailing respect the reading direction of the current locale, so a leading/trailing constraint will be left/right in English but right/left in Hebrew; Using leading rather than left makes localisation easier.  Perhaps update your question showing what is happening with a leading constraint as it should work the same as left.

Comment: `Leading` is the correct alternative to `Left`. The only difference is how the constraints behave in Right-To-Left languages. You need to check you have followed the tutorial correctly and have attached the constraints to the correct views with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the main constraints menu at the button of Xcode.

See below screenshot: click the element you want to add a constraints to and it will give you the options you need.

[image: Menu 1]

[image: Menu 2]

Cheers,
Tal